# How to analyze live Bluetooth packet in wireshark?

Tags: bluetooth, wireshark, libpcap, bluez, hci

If i use bluez hcitool, like `hcitool scan` then I could see packets in wireshark properly under interface bluetooth0. And I am sure that bluez in using on-board Bluetooth chip.

I have written my own application with  my own Bluetooth stack ( i am not using bluez ) for USB Bluetooth dongle (using libusb ), but when I start wireshark with bluetooth1 interface, then wireshark not show any packet.

Should my application send packets to wireshark? if so, can some one please direct me how to see my Bluetooth packets in wireshark?

Comment: I don't think you'll need to send the packets directly to Wireshark, you could try resetting and renaming the adapter, are you transmitting anything while monitoring?

Comment: mind sharing the code?

Comment: Yes I can share the code, but code is in multiple c++ file. Is there a way I can share all files as it is?